# Routes are not properly updating its just append the previous child route in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So  was trying to set nested routing under one `Layout` component
and I am not unable to navigate properly its just adding up previously visited route path to the URL while visiting new route path.

I have set up my routes like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<Layout Categorie={Categorie} />}> /*Parent Route*/
      <Route path='basket' element={<Basket />} />
      <Route path='checkout' element={<Checkout />} />
      <Route path='product/:productId' element={<ProductDetails />} />
      <Route path='categorie/:categoryId' element={<Categories />} />
    </Route> /*Parent Route end*/
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I am navigating to two components
first is to `<Categories />` Component:

```
<Link to={`categorie/${Categorie.Data[i].id}`}>{Categorie.Data[i].title}</Link>
```

and second is to `<ProductDetails />` component

```
1) <Link to={`product/${id}`}>{title}</Link>
2) <CategoryProductActionButton onClick={() => navigate(`product/${id}`) }>view 
   product</CategoryProductActionButton>
```

now the problem is can successfully navigate to `categorie/:categoryId`  that is `http://localhost:3000/categorie/1` url
but after that when I visit to  my `product/:id` route I got this `http://localhost:3000/categorie/1/product/1` although I was expecting it to be `http://localhost:3000/product/1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have new route and it's not child of current route then you have to pass "/" before any route.

```
<BrowserRouter>
<Routes>
  <Route path='/' element={<Layout Categorie={Categorie} />}> /*Parent Route*/
  <Route path='/basket' element={<Basket />}/>
  <Route path='/checkout' element={<Checkout />}/>
  <Route path='/product/:productId' element={<ProductDetails />}/>
  <Route path='/categorie/:categoryId' element={<Categories />}/>
  </Route> /*Parent Route end*/
</Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

and you link will be as

```
<Link to={`/categorie/${Categorie.Data[i].id}`}>{Categorie.Data[i].title}</Link>
```